# Mathcing data that includes "string1" and ends with "string2"

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-access

In Excel or Access(preferably) I want to do the following:
I have company names matched with their zip codes like:

> Ozer LTD-55200
>   Gelibolu INC.-34759

and also I have some strings like ze and ibolu which are substrings of the company names and I have a list of zipcodes. I want to extract from the companyname-zipcode list the companies that contain `ze` and ends with 55200 zipcode or another example: company name contains `ibolu` and ends with 34759 zipcode.

In short I need a function like: Matching strings that includes "xyz" and ends with "01234"

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query that has the criteria `LIKE "*ze*" AND LIKE "*55200"`

the first like has `*` at both ends of the comparison string to match anywhere
the second like only has a `*` at the beginning, so the matching string has to appear at the end

Comment: thank you for your answer but I need a generic formula for that since I have 1000 unique rows in total

Comment: to make the query generic, use `LIKE "*" & [field1] & "*" AND LIKE "*" & [field2]`